# Automatic turning on an android

Tags: boot, kernel

i have found a solution of the problem of automatic turning on an android (not samsung), when battery is charging for this i've inserting the line

```
/system/bin/reboot
```

in the file

```
/system/bin/ipod
```

on android 4.2 everything worked fine. now, i'm working on 4.4 Kitkat, and the same trick didn't worked. can you tell me, what could be the problem, and how to reach a final goal: automatically turn on the phone, when battery is charging?